# Pyspark: Insert rows with specific timestamp into dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have following Spark Dataframe:

```
   id  |  time                   |Value|    
   id1 | 2020-02-22 04:57:36.843 | 1.4 |
   id2 | 2020-02-22 04:57:50.850 | 1.7 |
   id3 | 2020-02-22 04:58:02.133 | 1.2 |
```

I want to insert rows between the existing ones with a certain timely distance (e.g. 5s).
The output should look like this:

```
   id  |  time                   |Value|    
   id1 | 2020-02-22 04:57:36.843 | 1.4 |
   id1 | 2020-02-22 04:57:41.843 |     |
   id1 | 2020-02-22 04:57:46.843 |     |
   id1 | 2020-02-22 04:57:51.843 |     |
   id2 | 2020-02-22 04:57:50.850 | 1.7 |
   id2 | 2020-02-22 04:57:55.850 |     |
   id2 | 2020-02-22 04:58:00.850 |     |
   id2 | 2020-02-22 04:58:05.850 |     |
   id3 | 2020-02-22 04:58:02.133 | 1.2 |
   id3 | 2020-02-22 04:58:07.133 |     |
   id3 | 2020-02-22 04:58:12.133 |     |
   id3 | 2020-02-22 04:58:17.133 |     |
```

I have tried do get this through a for-loop, creating new dataframes (of each new row) and merge it to the existing one by "union", which was not successful. I especially do not get the id by this approach.

Do you have an idea how I reach my desired output?

Comment: should the interval of 5 seconds be inserted thrice (hardcoded) ? if not please explain how do you get the last row of time for id1 before the starting row of id2 in the expected output..

Comment: how there is 62 seconds?

Comment: @anky: Yes, I actually need it hardcoded. I want to fill the values of these timestamps with values from another dataframe. The last values of shorter sequences (e.g. new sequence starts before the end of previous sequence) should be filled by padding.

Comment: @miket seems the answer below has worked for you, please consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my try with some modifications, for example, I can't understand how there exist 62 seconds.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql import Window

w = Window.orderBy('time')

df.select('id', 'time') \
  .withColumn('time', to_timestamp('time', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS')) \
  .withColumn('time2', coalesce(lead('time', 1).over(w), expr('time + interval 10 seconds'))) \
  .withColumn('seq', expr("sequence(time, time2 + interval 5 seconds, interval 5 seconds)")) \
  .withColumn('time', explode('seq')) \
  .select('id', 'time') \
  .join(df, ['id', 'time'], 'left') \
  .fillna(0).show(20, False)

+---+-----------------------+-----+
|id |time                   |Value|
+---+-----------------------+-----+
|id1|2020-02-22 04:57:36.843|1.4  |
|id1|2020-02-22 04:57:41.843|0.0  |
|id1|2020-02-22 04:57:46.843|0.0  |
|id1|2020-02-22 04:57:51.843|0.0  |
|id2|2020-02-22 04:57:50.85 |1.7  |
|id2|2020-02-22 04:57:55.85 |0.0  |
|id2|2020-02-22 04:58:00.85 |0.0  |
|id3|2020-02-22 04:57:59.133|1.2  |
|id3|2020-02-22 04:58:04.133|0.0  |
|id3|2020-02-22 04:58:09.133|0.0  |
|id3|2020-02-22 04:58:14.133|0.0  |
+---+-----------------------+-----+
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The 62 sec is, of course, nonsense. I edited it, thanks. I created this dummy dataset manually. 
The approach solved my problem!